# jQuery.repeater doesn't work with jQuery Ui sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, repeater, jquery.repeater

I am using [jQuery.repater](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) library for creating repeateble form. And i want sortable all repeateable fields with [jQuery Ui Sortable](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) library.

Everthing is ok but, when i sort repeatable fields, input name orders doesn't reindexing. As described [here](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater#example), it is possible with `ready` event.

Here is my code:

```
<form class="repeater">
    <div class="sortable" data-repeater-list="group-a">
      <div class="item" data-repeater-item>
        <input type="text" name="text-input" value="A"/>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
      </div>
      <div class="item" data-repeater-item>
        <input type="text" name="text-input" value="B"/>
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const form = $(".repeater");
  const sortable = $(".sortable").sortable({
    update: function() {
      console.log(form.serializeArray());
    }
  });

  $(".repeater").repeater({
    show: function() {
      $(this).slideDown();
    },
    hide: function(deleteElement) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this element?")) {
        $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
      }
    },
    ready: function(setIndexes) {
      sortable.on("sortchange", setIndexes);
    }
  });
});
```

And live:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pbdssq?file=index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem that I have been waiting for the answer for a long time as follows:

I called to `repeater.repeater("setIndexes")` the repeater at **each sortable operation.** [Reference](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater/issues/11)

```js
update: function() {
  myRepeater.repeater("setIndexes");
}
```

This makes it work correctly, but clicking the `Add Button` causes the problem of adding more than one element, so a change is required in the source code of `jquery.repeater.js`. [Reference](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater/issues/48)

In `jquery.repeater.js` we have to make the following changes:

**Before:**

```js
$filterNested($self.find('[data-repeater-create]'), fig.repeaters).click(function () {
    addItem();
});
```

**After:**

```js
$filterNested($self.find('[data-repeater-create]'), fig.repeaters).click(function (event) {
    addItem();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();   
});
```

You can find the working sample at [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ttymag?file=index.js).

*It shouldn't break anything but I haven't done any exhaustive testing.*

Comment: Thank you. It is nice solution.